# Magento:Custom dropdown cart - How to get "my cart" link?

Tags: php, xml, magento, shopping-cart, cart

I am working on a dropdown cart based on Magento's sidebar cart feature. Thanks to a tutorial I got this working when editing the checkout.xml and page.xml files, however I want to do it the real Magento way by just editing my local.xml file. Here's my code:

header.phtml

```
div class="top-cart">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topCart') ?>
<div class="top-cart-menu">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topCartBlock') ?>
</div>
</div>
```

local.xml

```
  <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topCartBlock" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-" >
    <action method="addItemRender">
      <type>simple</type>
      <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
      <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
    </action>
   <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
      <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
    </block>
  </block>
```

Up to this point it's working, I get the sidebar mini cart display in my header. But in order to implement the mouseover I need the cart link. When I put the above code with the following code in page.xml it's working, but not when I add it in my local.xml the link is not being displayed.

```
<reference name="top.cart">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>Your Cart</label>
    <url>checkout/cart</url>
    <title>Your cart</title>
    <position>1</position>
    <li/>
    <a>id="top-link-cart"</a>
  </action>
</reference>
```

How do I have to modify this code in order to  get the "My Cart" link?

Comment: You can create your own answer and accept it if you've found a solution that is working.

Comment: There is no need to mark the header with *[solved]* once you have accepted an answer (by clicking the tick mark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by substituting the last code part with

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="topCart" as="topCart"> 
  <block type="checkout/links" name="cart_link"> 
    <action method="addCartLink">
    </action>
  </block>
</block>
```

This gets us the link to the shopping cart which I will use as the mouseover link

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can delete your related comment and strip off (Edit) the reference in the answer to *beautify* it :-)